# Sending JSON files to iPhone for iOS app testing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, local-storage

I have developed my first iOS app and I am facing a relatively trivial problem. The app uses very basic data stored in a local json file. Right now I have placed the "default.json" file in a local directory that can be accessed by Xcode and iPhone 6.1 Simulator.

My simple app runs like a charm.

I can easily access the JSON file using the following declarations:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *jsonPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"default.json"];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:jsonPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

The local path to the json file is:
***/Users/kamil/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/CE00BA77-1CAD-4336-8A83-C95341CDF4AA/Documents/default.json***

Now, when I try to lunch my app on iPhone, my app crashes. Very quick inspection of the debugger log demonstrates there might be a problem with the access to the file on iPhone.

How can I store and access my defaul.json file from within an app running natively on iPhone?

Comment: Does the file exist in the documents directory on the iPhone? My guess is no, unless you are copying the file from your application bundle to the Documents directory when you launch your app. What is the crash log pointing to?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the file in the application bundle (ensure it's there in XCode, under the Copy Bundle Resources section on the Build Phases tab for the project), then access the file directly with no path, with simply `default.json`. However, any files in the application bundle are read only.

Alternatively, if you wish to be able to update the file, your app should typically copy the file from the application bundle to the documents folder on first launch, and then access the copy in the documents folder from then on. (Hint: If the file doesn't exist in the documents folder, copy it from the application bundle.)

When distributing an app, only the files included in the application bundle are delivered. When run on a device from XCode, only the application bundle is copied to the device, and all non-localized files are in the root folder of the application bundle.

Comment: Thank you very much! The solution worked like a charm! Simple and elegant!

Comment: @KamilTamiola, I'm glad I was able to provide the solution. Please don't forget to accept my answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If the solution mentioned by @Marcus Adams did not work for you. Try deleting the app in your phone and reinstall it...

Comment: Thank you! I did remove the app and built the project from a scratch on my iPhone. Everything works fine now! Thank you for your help